# In a deployed shinyapp, how to get the name of the account?

Tags: r, shiny

can't seem to find the info.
Let's say your shiny app's url is : "joe.shinyapps.io/great_app"
I'm looking to get that url from within that shiny app (running on shinyapps.io).

That way, the redirect URI I use for oauth could change dynamically based on which shiny app account I deployed the app to...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer while researching packages that do use user credentials oauth and shiny (those packages must use a redirect URI that is specific to the user's app). The following bit is taken from [GoogleAuthR package](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR/blob/5c2de57893b0674bfb63013471d42c4492da8ae6/R/googleAuthR_shiny.R).

```
if(!is.null(session)){
        pathname <- session$clientData$url_pathname
        hostname <- session$clientData$url_hostname
        port <- session$clientData$url_port

        url <- paste0(session$clientData$url_protocol,
            "//",
            hostname,
            if(port != "") paste0(":", port),
            if(pathname != "/") pathname)
```